# List all available display managers

Tags: display-manager

How can I get the list of all the display managers installed in my Ubuntu laptop from the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to search for `x-display-manager` meta used in Debian package that provide an X display manager.

Using aptitude:

```
aptitude search '~i~Px-display-manager'
```

Or debconf:

`./dm_list.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# source debconf library
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

# set default display manager
DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER_FILE=/etc/X11/default-display-manager

CHOICES=
if db_metaget shared/default-x-display-manager choices; then
  CHOICES="$RET"
fi

echo $CHOICES
echo default $DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER_FILE
```

`sudo ./dm_list.sh`

**References:**

- `DEBIAN/config` file from lightdm debian package
- [How do I get a list of packages that “Provides” something" using dpkg?](https://serverfault.com/questions/364608/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-packages-that-provides-something-using-dpkg)